# Get total number of text (words) in a react component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get the total number of text passed in a React component `GetText` from `Practice` Component but in the `useState` the total is appearing as individual values and I am unable to combine the total into one single value for all the children in the `GetText` component. I don't know what I am doing wrong, can someone help?

My ultimate intention is after getting the total number of text, I would calculate the read time for all the articles I write on this amazing personal website [lagustephen](https://lagustephen.com) where I planned to write about technologies that interest me to share what I have learned.

Here is the code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const GetText = ({ children }) => {
    const [totalNumberOfTexts, setTotalNumberOfTexts] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof children === "string") {
            // get string total text
            let total = children.split(" ").length;
            setTotalNumberOfTexts(totalNumberOfTexts + total);
        } else {
            // get nested text
            let getNestedText = children.map((el) =>
                el.props ? el.props.children : null,
            );

            //get number total nested text
            let getTotalNestedText = getNestedText.join(" ").split(" ").length;

            setTotalNumberOfTexts(totalNumberOfTexts + getTotalNestedText);
        }
    }, []);
    console.log(totalNumberOfTexts);

    return <p style={{ padding: "1rem 0rem" }}>{children}</p>;
};

const Practice = () => {
    return (
        <div style={{ padding: "1rem 2rem" }}>
            <GetText>Count Number text in GetText component</GetText>

            <GetText>
                Lorem ipsumsf dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem
            </GetText>

            <GetText>
                <span className="highlighted">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis
                    ex quos, veritatis, dolore e
                </span>{" "}
                <a href="https://lagustephen.com">see website</a>
            </GetText>

            <GetText>
                Lorem ipsumsf dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem
            </GetText>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Practice;
```

Comment: By "total number of text" you mean the number of words or do you mean the length in characters or the count of paragraphs?

Comment: Yes, @MarkE, that is correct, in fact, let me correct it, if that makes it clear, thank you!

Comment: Each component computes its own word count. Are you wanting to compute a "global" word count? If so then you need to lift state to `Practice` and pass a callback to each child `GetText` component for them to report back their word count.